# How to authorize or delerate JAAS security context with native libs (SSPI or MIT or Heimdal)

Tags: odbc, authorization, kerberos, jaas, delegation

I need to perform authorization or rights delegation within Active Directory on a chain JAAS (Java) -> Native APP with ODBC (C++) -> MS SQL Server. Any variant will do:

1. check if the user is valid and find out who it is;
2. delegate the users rights and access MSDB through ODBC.

Initially I receive a ticket created with this code:

```java
Oid KERB_V5_OID             = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
Oid KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2.1");

KerberosPrincipal kerberosPrincipal;

GSSManager    gssManager    = GSSManager.getInstance();
String        remoteSpnName = this.url + "@" + kerberosPrincipal.getRealm();
String        localSpnName  = kerberosPrincipal.getName();
GSSName       remoteGssName = gssManager.createName      (remoteSpnName, KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID);
GSSName       localGssName  = gssManager.createName      (localSpnName,  KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID);
GSSCredential localCreds    = gssManager.createCredential(localGssName, 0, KERB_V5_OID, 1);
GSSContext    gssContext    = gssManager.createContext   (remoteGssName, KERB_V5_OID, localCreds, 0);

gssContext.requestMutualAuth(false);
gssContext.requestConf(false);
gssContext.requestInteg(false);

byte[] ticket = gssContext.initSecContext(new byte[0], 0, 0);
```

It looks like I should use SSPI because I'm working on MS platform but I failed accepting the ticket. It seems that SSPI and JAAS use different formats.

Also I tried MIT library because of its open soure nature, so I can always look inside its code. Accepting the ticket with gss_accept_security_context gives me "unknown error FF 161".

I feel like I'm executing wrong call sequence trying to accept it.

All help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Kerberos is an old and complex beast; AFAIK Java has a (limited) support of good'old GSSAPI, where service tickets only care about authentication; while Monstrosoft built custom extensions into SSPI e.g. inclusion of group membership into the ticket (for authorization purposes) or constrained delegation. With Java clients I guess you have to use a GSSAPI lib server-side, then run queries against AD server-side to fetch groups, GPOs etc about that user.

Comment: Or maybe try to wrap communication inside a REST shell - SPNego auth is supported by most HTTP clients and servers; after the initial handshake and passing of Kerberos token, the server typically sends a session token to store in a cookie client-side.